# Scaling an SVG <img> to fit viewport

Tags: html, css, web, svg, responsive-design

Here's the WIP :
www.wearethefirehouse.com/wcftest

Logo is .SVG from Illustrator.

My code is (included the whole section for perspective, maybe conflicting div's?):

```
<!-- Intro Header -->
<header class="intro">
    <div class="intro-body">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <img src="img/master-logo-white.svg" alt="Wine Country Flooring Logo">
                    <a href="#about" class="btn btn-circle page-scroll">
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animated"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

If you shrink browser window you'll see that it STARTS fine, then jumps around a bit, finally settling at a uselessly large iteration by the time you're in a mobile viewport.

**How do I get it to scale cleanly?**

This is my first time with SVG and I know it's something I need to use more... trial by fire, right?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with SVG.  It's jumping around because of Bootstrap and the way it is resizing elements on the page based on page width.

If you don't want it to jump so much, you could use different bootstrap styles.  Eg.:

```
<div class="col-md-12>
    <img src="img/master-logo-white.svg" alt="Wine Country Flooring Logo">
    <a href="#about" class="btn btn-circle page-scroll">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animated"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Although that helped it scale smoothly up until the mobile viewport, it didn't really help the bigger issue.

1) The logo file is now HUGE to start, I liked the original size.
2) It still doesn't scale at the mobile breakpoint.

Comment: You are not forced to use the Bootstrap classes if you don't want to.  Just remove the `col-md-12` class from your div and style it how you want.

Comment: Made some tweaks and added a couple media queries and its all working how I wanted and the changes are live. Thanks for your help!